# Laptop HDD not mounting.

Tags: hard-drive

I have a laptop with broken (shorted out) motherboard  and a 640 GB HDD.

I want to recover my data from the hard disk.

Every time I connect the hard disk using an external casing, it is being detected in the disk management service but not visible in my computer, nor accessible through command prompt.

The Hard Disk is functioning as I can feel the hard disk rotor working properly when connected using the casing. Also the LED on the hard disk is blinking, the data is there but i am unable to access the data. Someone please suggest me ways of using the hard-disk as a slave disk using casing.

Comment: What file system type is the drive being detected as? Is it ntfs or 'unidentified'? Also, drives tend to spin as long as there's power so, the fact that it spins means very little

Comment: it says unidentified

Comment: ooh, not fun. At this point I'd boot into a linux livecd to see if its detected there, and give testdisk and other recovery tools a run

Comment: Did you set a HDD password in the old computers BIOS? If you did then the contents are like encrypted and it will only show up on the original laptop.

Comment: What interface does the external casing provide -- USB? If so, it might be the USB port does not provide enough power. You could take the HDD out of the casing, and connect it directly to a desktop. Then, look at what disk management tools say.

Comment: yes i had encrypted the hdd is there some way i can use it again

Comment: I decrypted the disk using truecrypt in another system, but still the issue is not resolved